# How to add SearchView query to FirestoreRecyclerOptions?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of chat rooms and each document contains a field called `name` which represents the name of the chat room and another field called `timestamp` that contains the timestamp of the last sent message. I created a recycler view of all chat rooms order by the timestamp. I would like to add support to SearchView. By using the search, user can search the chat room he wants. I tried:

```
Query chatRoomsQuery = db.collection("chatRooms")
        .whereArrayContains("users", documentRef.getPath()).orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ChatRoom> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatRoom>().setQuery(chatRoomsQuery, ChatRoom.class).build();
setupRecyclerView(options);

chatSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        Query chatRoomsQuery = db.collection("chatRooms")
                .whereArrayContains("users", documentRef.getPath())orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .startAt("name",newText).endAt("name",newText + "\uf8ff");
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ChatRoom> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatRoom>().setQuery(chatRoomsQuery, ChatRoom.class).build();
        setupRecyclerView(options);
        return false;
    }
});
```

But when typing some letter in the search I get an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many arguments provided to startAt(). The number of arguments must be less than or equal to the number of orderBy() clauses.

How can I query the firebase cloud database with different fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `startAt` and `endAt` are not how searching works in Cloud Firestore queries.

You're looking for:

```
db.collection("chatRooms")
  .orderBy("name")
  .whereArrayContains("users", documentRef.getPath())orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
  .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("name", newText)
  .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("name", newText + "\uf8ff");
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [query operators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators).

Comment: You get `You have an inequality where filter (whereLessThan(), whereGreaterThan(), etc.) 
 on field 'name' and so you must also have 'name' as your first orderBy() field, but your first orderBy() is currently on field 'timestamp' instead`.

Comment: Cool. So did you then add an `orderBy("name")`?